# Сторонние библиотеки

Tags: c++, cmake

Понадобилось подключить сторонние библиотеки в С++

Для подключения понадобилось написать CMakeList

```
 project(AXI) 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3) SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11") add_definitions(-DLINUX -D_GNUC_) if(WIN32)
        set(PATH_TO_MPLC_LIBRARY
                "/mnt/usb/files/c++/linux") # ПОМЕНЯТЬ НА СВОЙ

        set(PATH_TO_MPLC_INCLUDES
                /mnt/usb/files/c++) # ПОМЕНЯТЬ НА СВОЙ else()
        set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
        set(PATH_TO_MPLC_LIBRARY
                "~/Documents/work/Axitech/Project/cmake") # ПОМЕНЯТЬ НА СВОЙ

        set(PATH_TO_MPLC_INCLUDES
                "~/Documents/work/Axitech/Project/cmake") # ПОМЕНЯТЬ НА СВОЙ
    #link_directories(${PATH_TO_MPLC_LIBRARY}) endif()

    include_directories(
            ${PATH_TO_MPLC_INCLUDES}/include/core
            ${PATH_TO_MPLC_INCLUDES}/include
            ${PATH_TO_MPLC_INCLUDES}/lib
            ${PATH_TO_MPLC_INCLUDES}/lib/opcua)

    #set(MPLCLIBS masterplc opcua mplcshare) # mplcshare)
    #set(SYSLIBS pthread rt dl)
    #foreach (MPLCLIB ${MPLCLIBS})
    #        add_library(${MPLCLIB} SHARED IMPORTED)
    #        set_property(TARGET ${MPLCLIB} PROPERTY
    #                    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${MPLCLIB}.so)
    #endforeach ()

    set(INCLUDES        gpio_protocol.h         types.h)

    set(SOURCES
            gpio_protocol.cpp
            mplc_gpio.cpp) add_library(mplc_gpio SHARED ${SOURCES} ${INCLUDES})




    #target_link_libraries(mplc_gpio ${MPLCLIBS} ${SYSLIBS})

    #target_link_libraries(mplc_gpio ${MPLCLIBS} ${SYSLIBS})



    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(mplc_gpio PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

Все лежит на своих местах
[image: Вот каталог где все лежит]

Запускаю `cmake`, все идет гладко, но при запуске `make`:

> In file included from
>   /home/geo/Documents/work/Axitech/Project/cmake/gpio_protocol.h:3:0,
>                    from /home/geo/Documents/work/Axitech/Project/cmake/gpio_protocol.cpp:1:
>   /home/geo/Documents/work/Axitech/Project/cmake/types.h:2:30: fatal
>   error: shared/driver_fb.h: No such file or directory
>   Файл `type.h`

```
#pragma once
#include <shared/driver_fb.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
namespace axi {
    struct ChannelInfo : DriverVarDsc {
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<ChannelInfo> ptr;
        static ptr make() { return boost::make_shared<ChannelInfo>(); }

        std::string AddressGPIO;
    };

    typedef std::list<ChannelInfo::ptr> ChannelList;
}
```

Comment: А где находится `shared/driver_fb.h`?

Answer (score 2):

Не используйте тильду в путях, используйте полный путь:

```
set(PATH_TO_MPLC_INCLUDES "/home/geo/Documents/work/Axitech/Project/cmake")
```

или так:

```
set(PATH_TO_MPLC_INCLUDES "$ENV{HOME}/Documents/work/Axitech/Project/cmake")
```

А вообще Ваш CMake файл ужасен, конечно.

Comment: да, уже поменял, но результат тот же

Comment: @Geo, а где находится `shared/driver_fb.h`? и что выведет команда `message("Path to MLPC: " ${PATH_TO_MPLC_INCLUDES})` вставленная перед `add_library`?

Comment: спасибо) ошибка найдена